# How to access variables in different class from other class?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Let just say that we have two classes, `A` and `B`.
Here is code for both of them

```
class A
{
public:
    int x;
};

class B
{
public:
    int y;
    void FindY() { y = x + 12; }
};

void something()
{
    A fs;
    B fd;
    fs.x = 10;
    fd.FindY();
}
```

the problem is that i want to access x but i don't wanna pass anything as argument to my function i look at friend and inheritance but both didn't seem to help me, correct me if i'm wrong.
some how i need to find x in function `FindY()`.
I'm going with the static method but in my case i get this error.

Error   2   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class `std::vector<class GUIDialog *,class std::allocator<class GUIDialog *> > Window::SubMenu" (?SubMenu@Window@@2V?$vector@PAVGUIDialog@@V?$allocator@PAVGUIDialog@@@std@@@std@@A)  C:\Users\Owner\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Monopoly\Monopoly\Window.obj`
Here is how i declared it

```
static vector<GUIDialog *> SubMenu;
```

I get that error because of this line

```
SubMenu.resize(3);
```

Comment: `x` does not exist without an instance of `A`. You need to get it from *somewhere*.

Comment: You need to create an object of class `A` and then use `A.x`. Is that wat you are asking or am I missing something?

Comment: Why you don't want to pass the parameter to the function? I believe that is the basic question that needs to be solved rather than how to access `fs.x`.

Comment: Ok is not just one fs i'll be passing okay?

Comment: using static variable would be easier for me

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Three different approaches:

1. Make B::FindY take an A object as a parameter

   ```
   class B {
   public:
     void FindY(const A &a) { y = a.x + 12; }
   };
   ```
2. Make A::x static

   ```
   class A {
   public:
     static int x;
   };
   class B {
   public:
     void FindY() { y = A::x + 12; }
   };
   ```
3. Make B inherit from A.

   ```
   class B : public A {
   public:
     void FindY() { y = x + 12; }
   };
   ```

CashCow also points out more ways to do this in his answer.

Comment: Funny, I came up with a 4th approach: Have an A member in B.

Comment: @CashCow: or fifth: make x just static, outside any class :)

Comment: I thought of second method but can you tell me what this error means? `Error 2 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class std::vector<class GUIDialog *,class std::allocator<class GUIDialog *> > Window::SubMenu" (?SubMenu@Window@@2V?$vector@PAVGUIDialog@@V?$allocator@PAVGUIDialog@@@std@@@std@@A) C:\Users\Owner\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Monopoly\Monopoly\Window.obj
` i updated my post for more info

Comment: While the answer is technically correct, the Original Poster (OP) should be advised to learn what classes and objects really are.

Comment: @Jaywalker: You are probably right. I decided against writing a longer answer since I imagined that it would give the OP an opportunity to learn by himself, but I can't say that I'm entirely convinced by my own argument either...

Comment: +1 from me for teaching me how to include syntax-highlighted code in a list item when writing an answer. :-)

Answer (score 1):

As it is, `x` is not a variable of the class `A` but a variable of objects ("instances") of class `A`. There are at least two ways to make `x` accessible from `B::findY` without passing anything to the function:

- Instantiate an object of class `A` inside the `B::findY` function:

```
    class B
    {
    public:
        int y;
        void FindY() { A a; y = a.x + 12; }
    };
```

- Make `x` a static variable, so that it's a variable on the class itself. You don't need to instantiate objects in this case, but the variable will be common for all objects of type `A` (so you cannot have different values of `x` for different objects):

```
    class A
    {
    public:
        static int x;
    };

    class B
    {
    public:
        int y;
        void FindY() { y = A::x + 12; }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that A is correct and you cannot change it, i.e. x is a member variable, you will need an instance of an A in order to use its x member.

Thus said we can modify B but you need FindY() to take no parameters.

Therefore we need to bring in the A with an earlier call and store it as a class member.

```
class B
{
public:
   A a;
   int y;
   void FindY() { y = a.x + 12; }
};
```

This is just an outline. This is what is commonly done for "functor" classes where the function is operator() and takes a fixed number of expected parameters but we want more. The whole of boost::bind is based on this principle.