# C# Reaching objects from a different class

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm learning C# and I'm trying to make a game and I have a problem. I have two classes that I call `Item` and `Weapon`, `Weapon` looks something like this:

```
class Weapon : Item
{ 
    int damage; 
    int durability;

    public void asd()
    {
        Weapon shortSword = new Weapon();
        shortSword.dmg = 5;
        shortSword.durability = 20;
        Weapon woodenBow = new Weapon();
        woodenBow.dmg = 3;
        woodenBow.durability = 15;
    }
 }
```

Then I have another class containing different methods, one of them is called when the player walks on an item and its supposed to randomize that item. But I can't reach the objects in `Weapon` from this other class. How do I reach them, or solve this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access variables in different class from other class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507822/how-to-access-variables-in-different-class-from-other-class)

Comment: What do you mean by "reach the objects in `Weapon`"? Could you provide an example of code you *want* to work? An excerpt from this other class you've mentioned for instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a problem with your design. The method that creates weapons shouldn't be an instance method on the `Weapon` class. It could perhaps be a static method, or perhaps even a method on some other class.

Your method should return the weapons in a collection or as an `IEnumerable`.

```
public class Weapon : Item
{
    public int Damage { get; set; }
    public int Durability { get; set; }

    // Consider moving this method to another class.
    public static IEnumerable<Weapon> CreateWeapons()
    {
        List<Weapon> weapons = new List<Weapon>();

        Weapon shortSword = new Weapon { Damage = 5, Durability = 20 };
        weapons.Add(shortSword);

        Weapon woodenBow = new Weapon { Damage = 3, Durability = 15 };
        weapons.Add(woodenBow);

        return weapons;
    }
}
```

I also used the object initializer syntax to make the code more concise, and tidied up some of your method/property naming.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll read up on IEnumerable. It seems to work!