# Accessing variables from one class to another in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to access a variable declared in class `A` from class `B`, without using `static` variables. I have the classes separated in header and source files.

I have seen different people using pass by reference (I assume "const &a" declared in the class definition) but it doesn't work for me.

Update:When I tried to pass in the A object to the B::print as a const-reference parameter I got an error. In my example, I am trying to access `string a` from the function `void print` declared in `class B`. The problem now is that I am getting an error in `B.cpp`.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    A first;
    B second;
    second.print(cout, first);
return 0;
}
```

A.h

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;


class A
{
    string a = "abc";
public:
    A();
    void print(ostream& o) const;
    ~A();
};
```

A.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"

using namespace std;

A::A()
{
}

A::~A()
{
}

void A::print(ostream& o) const
{
    o << a;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, A const& a)
{
    a.print(o);
    return o;
}
```

B.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "A.h"

using namespace std;

class B
{
public:
    B();
    void print(ostream&, A const&) const;
    ~B();
};
```

B.cpp

```
#include "B.h"
#include "A.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

B::B()
{
}
B::~B()
{
}
void B::print(ostream& o, A const& a) const
{
    o << a << endl;
    //^^ error no operator "<<" mathes these operands
}
```

Comment: Hi there, you mention passing-by reference not working for you but I'm not seeing a pass-by reference in the above code. (You may have simplified your code a little too much.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507822/how-to-access-variables-in-different-class-from-other-class Check this out!

Comment: I didn't use it because i would have to upload all of the .cpp and .h files( I have 3 classes) .

Comment: *"I am trying to access a variable declared in class "A" from class "B""* -- either the "A" and "B" classes should be merged into a single class or (more probable) class "B" contains some logic that should stay in class "A".

Comment: Thanks for the link but I have already checked it out and tried using making a object as a parameter but it seems to not be working when I have the classes in separate files. Also I have aggregation between the two classes.

Comment: Your example should reflect your actual code. If your classes are in separate files, post an example that reflects these separate files. :-)

Comment: @KonstantinMechev `error no operator "<<" mathes these operands` you're getting that error since the compiler doesn't know how they should print your class. Have a peek at [Eljay's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53694423/10239789) on how to deal with that.

Comment: @TrebuchetMS I have uploaded all of the files, and I have implemented the answer. It works for a single file but in my case I am still getting the error.

Comment: @KonstantinMechev update your question with your new code and briefly describe how you're implementing it.

Comment: Put the `operator<<` overload in your `.h` file. Or add a `friend operator<< (ostream& o, A const& a)` in your `.h` file. Since we only include `.h` files, any functions declared in the `.cpp` files won't be included across your other class files.

Comment: Hi @KonstantinMechev, I think it would help if you would add comments to your code in order to show us what you think should happen and we can fix your flow.

Comment: @iosiG I updated my code according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/53694423/10767368 as suggested from other users.

Answer (score 1):

The way I'd do it is to pass in the A object to the B::print as a const-reference parameter.  I'd also pass in the ostream as a reference parameter.  And I'd take advantage of C++'s streaming output operator (`<<`).

Like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::ostream;
using std::string;

class A
{
    std::string s = "abc";
public:
    void print(ostream& o) const;
};

void A::print(ostream& o) const
{
    o << s;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, A const& a)
{
    a.print(o);
    return o;
}

class B
{
public:
    void print(ostream&, A const&) const;
};

void B::print(ostream& o, A const& a) const
{
    o << a << endl;
}

int main()
{
    A first;
    B second;
    second.print(cout, first);
}
```

UPDATE:  given the comments above, I'm not not sure if the problem is "How does one split up code into separate .h and .cpp files?" or if it is "How do I access A member variables from B, without using static variables in A?"

UPDATE: I changed A's member variable from `a` to `s` to disambiguate from other `a` identifiers.

Comment: The code works on one file, but it doesn't seem to work in my case. I am still getting the same error.

Comment: @Mechev That being the case, my guess is that the problem is downstream of the code:  how it is being compiled, or how it is being linked.  Could you update your post to show how you are compiling and linking?

Answer (score 1):

Since `a` is not a static member, it can't be accessed without an instance of class A. You can, however, pass one in the function:

```
class B {
    void print(const A &o) {
        cout << o.a << endl;
    }
};
```

In addition, if `a` member is private, you can declare `class B` as friend, which means it can access private and protected members of `class A`.

```
class A {
    friend class B;
private:
    std::string a = "abc";
};
```

Comment: @TrebuchetMS mb, mb